# materialize.js inside modal inside ng-view doens't work

Tags: angularjs, ng-view, materialize

triggered modal inside ng-view it works but not the inputs js inside it, such as select a date or select option input. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Include some code so I know what you're trying to do, but if you're using MaterializeCSS You'll need to include this for select tags to work.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select').material_select();
    });
</script>
```

This might not be what you're using, but if you link your code, I might be able to help with that.

Source: http://materializecss.com/forms.html

Edit:

At the bottom of the partial file, try this:

```
<script>
    $('select').material_select();
</script>
```

since it might be considered dynamic content, the jQuery on the index page might not be seeing it.

Comment: I'm unable to put it it says my comment is too long !

Comment: Go here. Paste your code, set the timer to an hour, or however long, set it public, then paste the url of your paste. http://pastebin.com/

Comment: I added an edit to the comment that might help. Also, are you including all libraries that you are using? I only see a link to jquery and materialize.js. They might be somewhere else, I'm just making sure that you have the materialize.css link, and a link for the lean modals. If my edit doesn't fix it, create a pastebin for the partial that the select is in.

Comment: That didn't work too!, i've deployed my app achievementsapp.firebaseapp.com you can register and check

Comment: I've inserted the script code in the end of the partial where it has the model still the js file seems not getting loaded inside this partial file!

Comment: The label looks like it outside of the partial, and it doesn't have a for="<<<the select's id>>>" But other than that... I ran into this issue with a select on a partial before. Try wrapping the code on the partial in a document.ready.

Comment: I did wrap the code in document.ready inside the partial still the select dropdown not working, the script file is also in index.html and the partial with the modal is inside meetings.html when i put the modal outside in index.html everything works, but inside the meetings.html as partial it doesn't

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help. You can add a class="browser-default" to get something for testing, but when I had the issue, I included that script at the bottom of the partial and everything worked. I'll play with it for a little while longer, and maybe find something soon. Question: What is the material-select inside of the select tag?

Comment: Link your jquery, and all that other stuff in the head of the index page. the calls on the partial might not yet have access to jQuery. I think that's it!

Comment: Thank you Carter, is there a way we can chat? I just included that tag for sake of trying to solve the issue! with browser-default class it works, but all the forms inputs needs .JS to work probably but that's not what i wanted

Comment: If you add me on skype, I'll be back in about 30 minutes. I don't know how long you'll be up, but send me a contact request and I'll message you when I can chat. I'll put my skype here for 10 minutes so It's not available to everyone. http://pastebin.com/AMK20ekF

Comment: Oh finally it worked, jquery issue and also the script tags should be inside the partial :) that's all :D

Comment: Another issue! the browse file input so there must another solution to initialise all the material.js inside the partial, i looked at the doc and there's no need for initialising the file input. I had to initialise the counter, too as they mentioned if the file is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using angular-materialize ?

http://krescruz.github.io/angular-materialize/#modals

Answer (score 0):

> You need to initialize your `select` as they mentioned above because when your script is loaded, the DOM is not ready still.